# Не удается удалить переносы строк с конца, а так же пробелы

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Мое первое выражение и то криво

```
'#^(?:\h*\R)+|\s+$|(?:\h*\R)+$#is'
```

Что мы тут делаем

`^(?:\h*\R)+`  //Удаляем переносы строк в начале текста, ок, работает, но как сделать чтобы не удаляла пробелы в начале строки. То есть пустые строчки, будь они пробелами или без - необходимо удалить

`\s+$` - Так пытаюсь удалить пробелы с конца строчки, не работает

`(?:\h*\R)+$` - пытаюсь удалить переносы строк с конца, тоже не работает.

Огромная просьба, в регулярках совсем не разбираюсь, сколько не пытаюсь, все не так...

Как составить регулярку под следующую задачу.

1. Необходимо удалить пустые строчки с начала текста и с конца, будь в
   них пробелы или нету, удалить. Главное текста и прочих символов не
   было
2. После того как первую задачу выполнили, необходимо оставить пробелы в начале строчки и удалить с конца (это в целом текст)
3. Далее построчно, после текста в строчке, необходимо удалить пробелы до переноса строчки. В каждой строчке

Comment: `preg_replace('#\A\s+|\s+\z|\h+$#um', '', $text)`

Comment: Попробуйте для тестирования регулярных выражений использовать сайты, которые позволяеют писать и проверять regexp в режиме реального времени. И которые сразу показывают результат, а так же предупреждают об ошибках. Например, https://regexr.com/  Тогда вы возможно не будете доспускать ошибок, которые есть в вашем примере. У вас указан в регулярке \h - но по сути это просто символ "H". Подозревают что вы перепутали или ошиблись. И хотели использовать \n - т.е. конец строки. Вот использование подобных сайтов может исключить такие ошибки.

Comment: Блин,  у меня совсем не работает данная конструкция https://regexr.com/765r9